# Using Inheritance for Generic Functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to create a template class with multiple children that override the template's methods (I believe I did this correctly). I then want a single function that can work with all of the children.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base{
public:
    virtual void print(void){
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
};

class inherit_a : public base{
public:
    virtual void print(void) override{
        cout << "inherit_a" << endl;
    }
};

class inherit_b : public base{
public:
    virtual void print(void){
        cout << "inherit_b" << endl;
    }
};

void print_function(base item){
    item.print();
}


int main(){
    inherit_a item_a;
    print_function(item_a);
    return(0);
}
```

This prints "base" like I would expect, however I would like it to use `inherit_a`'s print method or `inherit_b`'s print method if `inherit_b` was imputed to `print_function`. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you’re looking for is called *subtype polymorphism*; in C++, only reference types allow polymorphic `virtual` function calls to work as you expect. You can use a reference:

```
void print_function(base& item){
    item.print();
}
```

Or a pointer:

```
void print_function(base* item){
    item->print();
}
```

What you have done passes the object *by value*, copying the `base` portion of the object only—this is called *slicing*:

```
void print_function(base item){
    item.print();
}
```

Note that since your `print()` member function does not modify the object, it can and ought to be declared `const`. Also, `(void)` in parameter lists is C style and redundant in C++; use `()` instead.

```
virtual void print() const {
    cout << "Base" << endl;
}
```

The `const` is part of the signature, so subclasses must also specify it:

```
virtual void print() const override {
    cout << "inherit_a" << endl;
}
```

Then `print_function()` can take either a reference to a `const` object:

```
void print_function(const base& item){
    item.print();
}
```

Or a pointer to a `const` object:

```
void print_function(const base* item){
    item->print();
}
```

This documents that `print_function()` also does not modify its argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, and thank you for the additional information on const. I was able to get everything working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are taking in a `base` value to `print_function`.  Even if you pass a `inherit_a` instance it cause a new object to be created which is typed to `base` (called object slicing).  At the point `print_function` runs it is no longer a `inherit_a` value and hence won't call into the derived method.

What you are looking for is a reference to `base` to prevent slicing and allow the value to maintain its original type

```
void print_function(base& item){
  item.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Is something like this possible?" - Yeap, and it's called [polymorphism](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?256008-C-Polymorphism-What-is-polymorphism).